# mysql php datebase that will share a members table but nothing else?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm in the design phase of creating a php mysql database where groups will need to share a member table but will need to have their own tables for other data like messages, setting, attendance and so on.

I was thinking that I could create all the tables in one database and give each of them a group_id that would allow you to filter by that group and only show that data. This may have security issues and the database can get big.

The other way I was thinking of doing it was to create one database with members table with a group_id then create individual databases for each group. This is harder to visualize and harder to right querys.

My question is, is there a better way to do this or is it one of these two and if so witch one would you recommend and why?

Answer (score 1):

Security issues are programmer's fault, not database's.

Databases are meant to get *big* - the bottleneck is usually in poor php code, or in bug HTTP payload due to poor resource handling [no caching, useless requests, bad markup].

Just stick with one database, with well designed tables.

Comment: thanks for the fast response. So my idea to have a group_id for each table is a good idea?

Comment: You should have a table for each entity: a `members` table and a `group` table so far - check answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Why do groups to have their own tables with messages? That is very inefficient.

The structure you are describing is a called 1:n or 1 to many relation.

Just create a message table, with a field that points to the Group that the messages belong to:

```
CREATE TABLE `Groups` (
  `GroupId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`GroupId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `Messages` (
  `MessageId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `GroupId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Message` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`MessageId`),
  KEY `FK_Group` (`GroupId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_GroupMessage` FOREIGN KEY (`GroupId`) REFERENCES `Groups` (`GroupId`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: thanks your right Messages table was a bad example however there are tables that need to know witch group it is.